# page-break-inside is not working in table row with wkhtmltopdf conversion to pdf

Tags: html, css, html-table, wkhtmltopdf, page-break-inside

We're doing html to pdf conversion using wkhtmltopdf. We're using page-break-inside  and it is working when I'm checking it with window.print(), BUT when the html is converted to pdf the whole row which should be page breaked inside is on the next page. WHY?

[that's how it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXqEI.png)

[that's how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dn8Xe.png)

Comment: This is an old issue with wkhtmltopdf, make sure you have latest version installed. If you search google, you will find some old fixes, but think latest convertor does it correctly.

Comment: @skobaljic Thank you, unfortunately the latest version (0.12.6), even the 0.12.5 version have not fixed my problem.

Comment: Could be I misunderstood, the problem was wkhtmltopdf actually broke table row cells into two pages. What you want to achieve is kind of opposite and frankly I cannot imagine the way one can split say 5 columns row into 2 pages without breaking cells, to show only part of cell contents on first, or? Maybe you can use [this JS hack](https://gist.github.com/niflostancu/3683510).

Comment: @skobaljic I've added some illustration images for better understanding.